# How do I replace an img src attribute with HTMX

Tags: image, src, htmx

I'd like to replace the `src` attribute of an `img` element with the response of a form `post`.

What I'm doing right now is:

```html
<form hx-post="/myurl" hx-trigger="load,change" hx-target="#output" hx-swap="src">
</form>

<img id="output" src=""/>
```

but what I get is

```html
<img id="output" class="" src="">
out/528813151211e4736a4531358cda6af03fd3ce79a96d2f60108f3777e2715c92.webp
</src>
```

so, it appears a "class" attribute from nowhere and the value got from the post is not used as a value for the src attribute.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't read the documentation.  `hx-swap` cannot be used to set an attribute.  By default, it replaces `innerHTML` (which is what you see), and the other options are basically before or after the element.  https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap/

Comment: good, thanks. I'm sure that I found that example somewhere (maybe right on stackoverflow). Could you suggest me an alternative?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: The reason I didn't offer an alternative is that I couldn't find one in a few minutes of searching.  You may need Javascript for this.

Comment: HTMX can't do that. You should take a look at [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/docs/) instead, it was created by the same people who created HTMX. Hyperscript allows you to manipulate DOM elements.